# A good and basic implementation of BigInt class in C++

Tags: c++, biginteger, bigint

I'm looking for a good and basic BigInt class in C++, I find a lot of implementation but most of the time, it's complex implementation for crypto library...

By basic, I mean BigInt can deal with BigInt, long long and strings with operator overloading. 
If I had time, I had done myself but I do not have time to create an entire BigInt class.

Comment: I think GMP has class wrappers doesn't it?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes but GMP is in C. (I would like something in modern C++ who use operator overloading)

Comment: A _class wrapper_ would necessarily be in C++ since C doesn't have classes.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes you're right, my bad. But I don't want a professional library, but just a simple BigInt class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's one](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/). I haven't used it, but it doesn't look too complex, and it was the first result when I googled "bigint c++".

Comment: The library deal with many type other than BigInteger like BigUnsigned and BigUnsignedInABase, not so easy than just one BigInt class.

Comment: If you don't want BigUnsignedInABase, you're free to not use it. Personally, I don't think you'll find anything simpler. Take it or leave it.

Comment: I was wondering of something much more basic/easy.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest library I know of is [InfInt](https://github.com/sercantutar/infint). It consists of just one header file. Its usage is fairly simple. Here is a sample code:

```
InfInt myint1 = "15432154865413186646848435184100510168404641560358";
InfInt myint2 = 156341300544608LL;

myint1 *= --myint2 - 3;
std::cout << myint1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Here's an updated link to the [InfInt github](https://github.com/sercantutar/infint).

Here's a permanent download link for [InfInt.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20170509111229/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sercantutar/infint/master/InfInt.h)

Comment: This one seems not properly tested, try getting the fib numbers for up to 10 and see the results.

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/

C++ class BigInt that enables the user to work with arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: This one at least have some tests