# Big numbers library in c++

Tags: c++, biginteger

I'm doing a project which requires really big numbers, up to 100 digits. I have read that java supports big integers (`java.Math.BigInteger`), and I want to know if there is something like that in C++. So, here is my question: Is there a standard or non-standard c++ library which implements big integers?

**Note:** If there is no standard implementation for big integers, I would like a *simple* non-standard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can answer this with a simple websearch. For example: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have to say that I don't mind this as long as there isn't a duplicate SO question; SO questions get improved over time, and the best answers can rise to the top. Essentially this question is more about filtering the possibilities (what should I use) rather than finding them. It's not worded that way, and it is a slightly lazy question, but at least we'll have an answer for it on SO.

Comment: This question is offtopic because it asks for a library. The accepted answer is only useful to those future visitors who don't mind placing their entire program under the GNU Public License.

Comment: @Kaz The second sentence of your comment makes no sense, GMP is under **L**GPL.

Comment: My implementation here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117799/N-An-experimental-multithreaded-bignum-library-for

Comment: Also see [How to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940572/608639) It shows you how to use Botan, Crypto++ and OpenSSL big numbers. OpenSSL `BIGNUM` is even wrapped in C++ classes to provide operator overloading and resource management for you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library does what you want http://gmplib.org/

Gnu MP is a C library but it has a [C++ class Interface](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html) and if you are interested only in big integers, you may just deal with `mpz_class`. Look at the sample below which I took from the page [C++ Interface General](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html)

```
 int main (void)
 {
   mpz_class a, b, c;

   a = 1234;
   b = "-5678";
   c = a+b;
   cout << "sum is " << c << "\n";
   cout << "absolute value is " << abs(c) << "\n";

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I would like a simple implementation

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes bignum implementations are not simple

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Simple implementation or simple interface? GMP's interface is not so simple, but it's easy to get used to. And it is powerful and efficient.

Comment: Not thrilled. Not enough to downvote, but (1) The question is tagged C++. GMP is C. (2) A good C++ interface will be easy to use; e.g., addition is just '+'. (3) The question asked for big integers. GMP is bignums of all sort.

Comment: @DavidHammen Maybe I should have addressed a specific part of GMP, not the whole library. About (1) and (2), GMP v5 has a C++ class Interface http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html which has also overloaded some operators.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, there is no standard library for big numbers. You said you are looking for a "simple" library, the simplest library I know of is [InfInt](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/). It consists of just one header file. Its usage is fairly simple. Here is a sample code:

```
InfInt myint1 = "15432154865413186646848435184100510168404641560358";
InfInt myint2 = 156341300544608LL;

myint1 *= --myint2 - 3;
std::cout << myint1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Any idea how fast is that compared to gmp ?

Comment: Link is broken. Project "infint" has moved to another location on the Internet.

Comment: @ElefEnt: I tried both of them, GMP was several orders of magnitude faster in my case. (63 minutes vs. 40 seconds for a certain task.) However, I used the highly optimized [MPIR](https://github.com/wbhart/mpir) port of GMP.

Comment: InfInt is incredibly slow! A couple of order of magnitude slower them GMP!

Comment: why did you repost from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801910/995714?

Comment: Anyone looking for the library's working link: [it's in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576314/a-good-and-basic-implementation-of-bigint-class-in-c/16801910#comment74771458_16801910).

Answer (score 6):

You said you want a simple interface/implementation, here's one http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html. Personally I'd still go for GMP however.

Answer (score -1):

You will be taking input in a char array, and then will change it into an int array. The size of array can also be changed.

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int b, i, arrayint[100];
    char arraychar[100];

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cin >> arraychar[i];

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << arraychar[i];

    cout << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        arrayint[i] = arraychar[i] - '0';

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << arrayint[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not good C++ practice.