# deserializing very large numbers in c++

Tags: c++, serialization, largenumber, qbytearray

I'm supposed to write a code that can deserialize numbers that are received from another device using serial port (RS232) in the form of a `QByteArray` without using bitwise operators. The `QByteArray` can contain any length of data from a single item to more than 20 items or even more. Is this possible?

The solution I've come up with so far is:

```
int numelems = 0;
int exp = 0;
for(int i = tempba.size() - 1 ; i > -1 ; --i) {
    numelems += (unsigned char)tempba.at(i) * pow(256, exp);
    ++exp;
}
```

where `tempba` is a `QByteArray` filled with data read from a serial port. Is this approach correct? where can it be failed? any better way to achieve this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @DaleWilson descriptin is updated

Comment: Questions:  Is this correct?  Answer: Create a unit test and see if you get the expected results.  Question: Where can it fail?   Answer: Create a unit test and see if you can break it.   Question: Is there a better way to achieve this.   Answer: Probably.  What criteria are you using to measure better.  (speed, code clarity, safety, .... ?)  [hint: avoid the pow function for this type of work. `x *= 256` is your friend.]

Comment: This code can fail ([integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)) if `tempba` has more than 4 bytes (because int type usually is 32 bits = 4 bytes)

Comment: @Rimas yes it does. how can i achieve the desired results? I think dynamic conversion from an arbitrary length `QByteArray` is not possible since we have no containers to hold the large results.

Comment: You can use [uint64_t or int64_t integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (8 bytes), use integers array, but it's unclear what is your desired result? What plan you do with these large numbers?

Comment: @Rimas the intention is to find a dynamic way that is not constrained by the number of digits to deserialize a number and display it as a decimal number. the only way to display it is using a string but how to obtain the numbers from an arbitrary sized byte array which is safe and won't fail even with ridiculously large byte arrays is what matters and i don't think achieving that level of dynamicity is impossible.

Comment: Then maybe this is answer to your question: [Big numbers library in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12988099/3908097)

Comment: @Rimas GMP looks very promising I'll give it a shot thanks for the info.