# How to work on intergers as large as 2^9000000 in C++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, unsigned-long-long-int

The largest data type for positive integers I know of is unsigned long long. Is there a way to work on integers as large as 2^9000000 in C++.
I use gcc compiler in code-blocks but can also work on visual studio.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the value.

Comment: One option it to use a [big integer library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12988099/10957435).

Comment: You can use a library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Trying to do all that a library like that gives you, by hand, is likely to involve man-years of work. Just use an existing "arbitrary precision" library already.

Comment: There is also [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: ***Is there a way to work on integers as large as 2^9000000 in C++***  Nothing built into the language. Either use a library or write your own (academic exercise only).

Comment: @drescherjm That's also a fine option. And there are more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

Comment: Very often when posed with a problem like this there is a trick you can use, Modular exponentiation is a classic, to avoid having to handle such large numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some kind of BigInt library. I personally prefer [boost.multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), as it contains most of the utilities an average code writer would need.

In terms of what you actually want to use, there's two obvious types to consider.

- If you just need arbitrarily sized integers, `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` is the way to go, which will store a number as big as 2^9000000 by allocating approximately 9 million bits of data (slightly more than one megabyte) and storing the entire number in there.
- If you need big numbers, but don't need to preserve the precision of every last digit, you'll prefer something like the `cpp_bin_float` backend, although for that you'd probably have to define your own template, since the prebaked versions probably aren't big enough.

For the latter, a potential example:

```
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using my_big_float = number<backends::cpp_bin_float<100, backends::digit_base_2, void, boost::int32_t, -9000000, 9000000>, et_off>;
//Defines the number to have 100 bits of precision, an exponent range from negative
//nine million to positive nine million, and uses 32-bit ints for the internal representation
//of the exponent. Allocator is void (because we don't need it) and et_off just turns off 
//expression templates, which we don't need

int main() {
    my_big_float fl = 5;
    fl = pow(fl, my_big_float{900007});
    std::cout << fl << std::endl;
}
```

```
7.88302e+629077
```

I don't know what your use-case is, but my guess is that the latter is going to be much better for your use-case than the former. You'll have to decide for yourself what the case is.