# How to store/assign value to a data type greater than it's range

Tags: c++, unsigned-long-long-int

I wrote a simple code to print the simple series where the current number multiply with the previous number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i; 
    unsigned long long result = 1;

    std::cout << "please enter the number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        result = result*i;
    }

    cout<<result;

    return 0;
}
```

output

please enter the number
65
9223372036854775808(this is the highest value as a result obtained for unsigned long long)
Now if the input is 66 it gives the output as 0(since it exceeded the range of unsigned long long)

How I can obtain a result for the variable which exceeds the data type range?

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible. You'll need to use a data type that can hold the values.

Comment: ***How I can obtain a result for the variable which exceeds the data type range?*** You can't do that. you need to lose precision or switch to a big math library. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c)

Comment: That product has a name; it's called the factorial.

Comment: @drescherjm got the point.