# How to show large integer numbers on C++

Tags: c++

I am developing a single code that calculates **Fatorial Number on C++**.

### The code

```
// Exemple:  5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number, total;
    cout << "Calculate fatorial number" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Type a number... ";

    cin >> number;

    total = 1;
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i-- ){

       if (i == number){
           total = i * total;
           cout << number << "! = " << i << " x ";
       } else if (i > 1) {
             total = i * total;
             cout << i << " x ";
       } else {
             total = i * total;
             cout << i << " = ";
       }
    }

    cout << total;
    return 0;
}
```

### The problem

When I give it numbers, do not return as expected.

### What I want

I Want to know how bypass the bigger number problems so I can calculate at least 100!

### Codes Output

- number = 10; total = 3628800
- number = 20 ; total = -2102132736

### Compiler used

[OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: Hint: Use a 64-bit integer if you need a larger [numeric range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). For numbers larger than that find a ["bignum" library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c).

Comment: You may want to read up on [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) if you're not familiar with it already. It explains why numbers "wrap" negative if they get "too big" and overflow.

Comment: You are overflowing the int, use unsigned int

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: @AndreNevares [See this example of boost multiprecision](https://ideone.com/e1sGBS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use an existing library that deals with large numbers, or implement your own. There's many options, gnu multi-precision, boost, etc...

If you choose to implement your own, you'll store digits in something like:

- A string `"90120304153543643626424262"`
- A `std::vector<int>` of digits (base 10)
  `{9,0,1,2,0,....}`
- A `std::vector<int>` of digits (large base, for efficiency. 2^16 works well)
  `{42567, 29183, 10987, ...}`

Then, you'd need to roll your own multiplication, addition, assignment.

Comment: Thanks man!  I will study everything you had posted here!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are searching for [bignum arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). You probably need to select some arbitrary-precision arithmetic library like [GNU MP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) and use it.

Comment: Thanks!   I will deep into your contribution.   Thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 0):

hello the way i solve for large numbers is by doing this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long int bigint; //big int 
int main() {

bigint total = 9494949494949497989;
cout<<total<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

so i make a custom data type called bigint and then instead of doing `int total` i do `bigint total`  thus i am able to store large int values

Comment: That isn't big enough for 100 factorial.